# jQuery on button click redirect and post data

Tags: jquery, html

I'm using a button within a dropdown to redirect when the button is clicked. The button also has an id="" attribute containing an ID which I want to post to the redirected page. To do this, I have used [jQuery.redirect](https://github.com/mgalante/jquery.redirect/blob/master/jquery.redirect.js) from github.

When I click the button nothing happens, I'm using firebug and no errors are present in the console. Where have I gone wrong?

Here is the script

```
            <script type="text/javascript">
                $( document ).ready(function() {
                    $(".triangle input[name='tedit']").click(function(){
                        var subID = $(this).attr('id');
                        $.redirect("/profile/subscriptionedit.php",{ subscription: "subID="+ subID, });
                    });
                });
            </script>
```

And the Div's containing the button to be pressed (The button to be pressed is name="tedit")

```
<div class="dropdownContain">
    <div class="triangle"></div>
    <ul>
        <li><button>Invoices</button></li>
        <li><button name="tedit" id="'.$id.'">Edit</button></li>
        <li><button id="'.$id.'">Cancel</button></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

The above is in a PHP foreach echo, which is why $id is displayed as "'.$id.'"

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#triangle input[name='tedit']").click(function(){
```

You have an id onclick

But your HTML has a class,change it to an id

```
<div id="triangle"></div>
```

Comment: Still no action when the button is pressed

Answer (score 0):

Changed

```
$("#triangle input[name='tedit']").click(function(){
```

to

```
$(".tedit").click(function(){
```

and added

```
class="tedit"
```

to the button which I wanted to perform the action.